# File does not get converted to base64 string properly

Tags: flutter, camera, base64

So I have written some code to capture an image from the user using the better_camera package and then store it in a file. Then I convert it to base64 string for further use. It seems like the image is getting saved properly since Image.file shows the image. But when I convert the image to base64string, it gives the image of a small white screen. I do not know where the problem is coming. Can someone check?

**CODE**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_better_camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:frappe/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class AddNewCameraItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewCameraItem({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddNewCameraItemState createState() => _AddNewCameraItemState();
}

class _AddNewCameraItemState extends State<AddNewCameraItem> {
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initCam();
  }

  void initCam() async {
    List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.secondaryColor,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'ADD NEW ITEMS',
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.bodyText1.override(
            fontFamily: 'Noto Serif',
            color: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 4,
      ),
      body: !controller.value.isInitialized
          ? Container()
          // : Image.file(File(
          //     '/data/user/0/com.flutterflow.frappe/cache/lkpbpyigaqpjsh6iygy8dA4dsFDG9CAcVD7DueDLtd3C3JqzmmRuZcKaFFmAt88Ryyp208CzlE1oYfkJKnvwErBFv3DkO0dSYLZApETWDnsGOur728R7WgoUQ1EEOv9ilz1jAeNLotSsYFaI13Jk9wp5mmGdqhmRx6LYSCfHQHAdalrMCtniqrU3Sqhaw1iJZfeuUsJy.jpg')),
          : MaterialApp(
              home: CameraPreview(controller),
            ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
            String randomName =
                tempDir.path + '/' + getRandomString(200) + '.jpg';
            // await controller.takePicture(randomName);
            File file = File(
                '/data/user/0/com.flutterflow.frappe/cache/IfXsEjNsSifPiQJ0d628j2d1HRh2Ww2Flin3urZc4d59WYeZ9DQ8mjpLdrt2jwzBjn2vxqvnkzRd4AGowI6fKCGRNWOfei7B2KufbpOG0RsNH7mobwGa7KS7q1C6ALoNIVJ13XLqpa7BX7pIQSgLobe5lW6z7P01QBms3CVrM9omeEvIZxRwxL5s555HLOGN4Te9Bta2.jpg');
            Uint8List list = await file.readAsBytes();
            print(list);
            print(base64Encode(list.toList()));

            print("Random n: " + randomName);
            // print(base64Encode((await xfile.readAsBytes()).toList()));
          } catch (e) {
            print("Error: " + e.toString());
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt, color: FlutterFlowTheme.tertiaryColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String getRandomString(int length) {
    String _chars =
        'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
    Random _rnd = Random();
    return String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
        length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
  }
}
```

**BASE64OUTPUT**

```
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
```

**UINT8LIST**

```
[255, 216, 255, 225, 11, 171, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 11, 1, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 146, 1, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 154, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 172, 1, 27, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 180, 1, 40, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, 188, 1, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 250, 2, 19, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 135, 105, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 14, 136, 37, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 242, 0, 0, 2, 248, 88, 105, 97, 111, 109, 105, 0, 0, 82, 101, 100, 109, 105, 32, 78, 111, 116, 101, 32, 53, 32, 80, 114, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 1, 119, 104, 121, 114, 101, 100, 45, 117, 115, 101, 114, 32, 57, 32, 80, 75, 81, 49, 46, 49, 56, 48, 57, 48, 52, 46, 48, 48, 49, 32, 86, 49, 49, 46, 48, 46, 53, 46, 48, 46, 80, 69, 73, 77, 73, 88, 77, 32, 114, 101, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 45, 107, 101, 121, 115, 0, 0, 50, 48, 50, 49, 58, 48, 56, 58, 49, 56, 32, 49, 57, 58, 49, 5
```

Comment: You have to decode before using the Base64 string ```String encoded = stringToBase64.encode(credentials);``` ```String decoded = stringToBase64.decode(encoded);```

Answer (score -1):

You have to decode before using the Base64 string

```
String encoded = stringToBase64.encode(credentials); 
String decoded = stringToBase64.decode(encoded);
```

Comment: Uhm. This isn't working. I dont feel like you did any testing before putting this answer because a) thats not how base64 works b) Decoding returns a Uint8List, Not a string. I think the problem is that it was working, but visual studio did not want to print a big string. Thank you for your help anyway. I'll update answer once I am sure